# Floating Column(Max/Min) Graph in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to create a graph as shown in the image below. I have the values for the upper limit, lower limit and the average for each question. Can anyone suggest a plugin in Ruby on Rails to create such a graph shown in the image?

[image: needed graph]

Edit:

I am finding it difficult to find something which does clear the area from the X-axis(Question axis) to the lower limit. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has a URL based chart API that and it looks like some of the chart types available will match what you are looking for:

Chart Gallery:
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/chart_gall.html

Getting Started Guide:
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/making_charts.html

Comment: +1 for google charts.  The documentation was a bit basic when i used them (~2 years ago) but once you get your head around the variable names then they're very simple to use.  I would avoid flash as domsterr suggests purely because of the iphone/ipad issue.  Also flash seems like a overly heavyweight solution to showing a simple unanimated graphic on a page.

Comment: @ctcherry..thanks for introducing me to Google chart API. At first, I was not sure a URL API based chart tool will be so powerful. When I looked into it in detail, I was amazed by its vast use. Google rocks. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mind if the output is in flash?

PullMonkey is a pretty nice plugin if it's not a problem to you http://pullmonkey.com/projects/open_flash_chart